# JAVA OPC UA Client can't connect to Kepware Server

Tags: java, opc-ua

I'm trying to get a minimal OPC UA Client to connect to a kepware Server.
I've tried both the OPC Foundations's stack and the SDK from Eclipse Milo.

It seems like the server URL can be resolved, however if I try to read anything from the server, it says something about the session being invalid.

Here's the code for the OPC UA Stack Client:

public class SampleClient {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String url = "(serverurl)";
        System.out.print("SampleClient: Connecting to " + url + " .. ");

        final Client myClient = Client.createClientApplication(null);


        SessionChannel mySession = myClient.createSessionChannel(url);
        // mySession.activate("username", "123");
        mySession.activate();

        EndpointDescription[] endpoints = myClient.discoverEndpoints(url);
        EndpointDescription endpoint = endpoints[0];

        ServiceChannel myChannel = myClient.createServiceChannel(endpoint);
        // Create Test Request
        ReadValueId[] nodesToRead = {new ReadValueId(Identifiers.RootFolder,                                                                                                                                                        Attributes.BrowseName, null, null)};
        ReadRequest req = new ReadRequest(null, 100.0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, nodesToRead);
        System.out.println("REQUEST: " + req);

        ReadResponse res = myChannel.Read(req);
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + res);

        //close
        mySession.close();
        mySession.closeAsync();
    }

}
```

And this is the code with the Eclipse Milo SDK

```
    public class MinimalClient {

    private OpcUaClient createClient() throws Exception {

        EndpointDescription[] endpoints;

        endpoints = UaTcpStackClient
                .getEndpoints("(serverUrl)")
                .get();

        EndpointDescription endpoint = endpoints[0];

        OpcUaClientConfig config = OpcUaClientConfig.builder()
                .setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english("MinimalClient"))
                .setApplicationUri("urn:serverURN")
                .setCertificate(null)
                .setKeyPair(null)
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .setMaxResponseMessageSize(uint(50000))
                .setIdentityProvider(new AnonymousProvider())
                .setRequestTimeout(uint(5000))
                .build();

        return new OpcUaClient(config);
    }

    public void readValue(OpcUaClient client, CompletableFuture<OpcUaClient> future) throws Exception {

        // synchronous read request via VariableNode
        VariableNode node = client.getAddressSpace().createVariableNode(Identifiers.Server_ServerStatus_StartTime);
        DataValue value = node.readValue().get();

        System.out.println(value);
    }

    private CompletableFuture<List<DataValue>> readServerStateAndTime(OpcUaClient client) {
        List<NodeId> nodeIds = ImmutableList.of(
                Identifiers.Server_ServerStatus_State,
                Identifiers.Server_ServerStatus_CurrentTime);

        System.out.println(client.readValues(10000.0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, nodeIds));
        return client.readValues(10000.0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, nodeIds);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<OpcUaClient> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        MinimalClient c = new MinimalClient();
        OpcUaClient client = c.createClient();
        client.connect();
        client.getAddressSpace();
        c.readValue(client, future);
    }
}
```

OPC UA Stack Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" ServiceFault: Bad_SessionIdInvalid (0x80250000) "The session id is not valid."
```

Eclipse Milo Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_SessionClosed, message=The session was closed by the client.
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong. Our Kepserver doesn't use any certification etc. The SecurityPolicy is None.

Comment: In the Milo example, try calling `client.connect().get()` before trying to read.

Comment: That worked. Seems I didn't look close enough. Thank you

Comment: There are no known issues regarding the Foundation Stack either. Your client seems to initialise two different channels. If you follow the SampleClient, it only initialises a SessionChannel and uses that. By default, createSessionChannel will select the best security level, though. But you can provide the endpoint that you choose from discoveryEndpoints instead. Also, you can use EndpointUtil.select() to select a suitable endpoint. If it still fails, we would need a more full stack trace. Better to report this to GitHub, if it persists.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this OPC UA stack is kind of confusing to me. Your suggestion worked and I can compare the Stack with the Milo SDK now.